# remove view controller from navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have 5 view controllers in navigation controller, and I want to remove Pages three and four on page five.The problem with below code is, if i remove index 3 and index 4 and I am on page Five.I get no back button on top anymore.I should be getting back button to page 2 again.But no.  what is the solution? Thank You for all the help provided.Appreciated. This error really driving me crazy

> navigationController!.viewControllers.remove( at: 3 )
>      navigationController!.viewControllers.remove( at: 4 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a cleaner way to do this is to modify the array of `viewControllers` and then set them back on the navigation controller like this..

```
if let nav = self.navigationController {
    var stack = nav.viewControllers
    // index starts at 0 so page three index is 2
    stack.removeAtIndex(2)
    stack.removeAtIndex(3)
    nav.setViewControllers(stack, animated: true)
}
```

I just tested this on one of my navigation stacks and the back button was retained, I assume this is due to the `setViewControllers` method doing it's thing and setting up the stack for you.